# Como criar layout igual ao do Hubspot

Tags: html, css

Boa noite, gostaria de saber se tem como descobrir se um sistema utiliza algum template ou biblioteca de css, o sistema em questão é o hubspot. Gostaria de criar algo parecido e se alguém souber o nome do template ou bibliotecas usadas eu agradeço !

Answer (score 0):

Boas

Pode procurar saber as tecnologias utilizadas em sites especializados.

https://stackshare.io/hubspot/hubspot

Comment: Muito obrigado !!!!!!